# How to configure a Security Group to allow an ECS container instance to reach Aurora RDS in a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-batch

Using Terraform I have configured a batch job definition, job queue, and compute environment that allows for job submissions on AWS Batch. The job launches an ECS container that runs a Python script which makes a connection to an Aurora database that is in a VPC to load data from an S3 bucket.

The jobs are timing out because the Python code can't make a connection to the Aurora (PostgreSQL) database:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "my-dev-aurora-postgres-1.cluster-cnjnya0rtdiq.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (10.191.52.225) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

How do I attach a Security Group or utilize another mechanism to allow the Python code running in the Docker container in ECS to connect with the Aurora RDS instance which is within a VPC?

Comment: Do the ECS containers run in private subnets?

Comment: Yes, the two subnets used for the compute environment are both private.

Comment: Can you provide details of your security group setup? Generally SG for the db instance would allow inbout traffic form SG of the ECS interface (assuming `awsvpc` networking mode).

Comment: All ports are open on ingress and egress both 
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
Bear in mind I am a rookie with this please advise if there's a more secure setting that will work for simple ECS to RDS communication. I assume that I will tighten security after I get it working with looser restrictions. Also both private subnets have routes to transit gateway which I think gives access to internet.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the related security groups of both the Aurora cluster and either the ECS service if it's using AWSVPC networking mode or the ECS cluster if you are using bridge or host networking modes? Ideally the Terraform you are applying but if not then then the output of the relevant describe AWS CLI calls. Can you also show the Terraform used to create the batch job?